# Comparison of a number with strftime() works inconsistenly

Tags: sqlite

I want to select today's visited urls from the firefox database places.sqlite.
As first attempt, the query I used to accomplish this was (see the operator `>`):

```
SELECT datetime(moz_places.last_visit_date/1000000,'unixepoch'), moz_places.title
FROM moz_places
WHERE moz_places.last_visit_date/1000000>strftime('%s','now','start of day')
ORDER BY moz_places.last_visit_date DESC;
```

The answer to this query is nothing.

Then I changed the query to this, which is pretty much the same (see the operators `-` and `>`):

```
SELECT datetime(moz_places.last_visit_date/1000000,'unixepoch'), moz_places.title
FROM moz_places
WHERE moz_places.last_visit_date/1000000-strftime('%s','now','start of day')>0
ORDER BY moz_places.last_visit_date DESC;
```

then the answer is correct.

Does anybody out there know why `>` works in one query by does not in the other?

Answer (score 0):

The `strftime()` function always returns a string, and a string always compares larger than a number.

When you try to use a string with addition/subtraction, it is automatically converted into a number first, so the result of `last_visit_date-strftime(...)` is a number.

You could change the function call in the original query to:

```
CAST(strftime('%s', ...) AS NUMBER)
```

or, less obvious, if you want to save typing:

```
strftime('%s', ...)+0
```